# Definition of numerical stability of algorithms

Tags: numerical-methods, algorithms

In a numerical analysis class, we were given a definition of algorithm stability:

**Def:** The algorithm $\tilde F:X\rightarrow Y$ for solving a problem $F:X\rightarrow Y$ is said to be **stable** if $\forall x\in X,\ \exists\tilde x\in X$ such that:
$$\frac{\|\tilde x-x\|}{\|x\|}=\mathcal O(\epsilon_{\text{mach}})\quad \text{and}\quad
\frac{\|\tilde F(x)-F(\tilde x)\|}{\|F(\tilde x)\|}=\mathcal O(\epsilon_{\text{mach}})$$
where $\epsilon_{\text{mach}}$ is the machine precision.

In other words: the algorithm is stable if it gives the nearly right solution to the nearly right problem.

My confusion with this definition is, that it seems to claim that some algorithms are stable even though intuitively they shouldn't be. For example, suppose the problem we are solving has sensitive dependence on initial conditions, say $F:[0,1]\rightarrow [0,1]$ computes some fixed large number $N$ of iterations of the [logistic map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_map). Suppose also that we propose a garbage algorithm $\tilde F(x)=1\ \ \forall x$. It seems to me, that for any initial condition $x\in [0,1]$ there will be another point $\tilde x$ close to $x$ such that $F(\tilde x)$ will be close to $1$. Does this not mean then that $\tilde F$ would be stable?

To make $\tilde F$ even worse, we could consider $\tilde F(x) = (\text{pseudo random number with seed x})$. The same argument seems to say that this $\tilde F$ is also stable. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I believe the definition you were given is for *backward* stability.  Your intuition is based on a notion of *forward* stability.  If these terms are not used in your study materials, I'd be happy to give an answer pointing to the difference in the definitions.

Comment: Thank you, that would be great! We covered the second kind of stability in class as well, but it was not very different and had the same problem. Anything that you could clarify would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I learned a bit more and I'll try to answer this.
The algorithm described here is stable (both forward and backward). But the stability of the algorithm alone isn't useful. To get accurate answers to some problem, two conditions need to be met:

1. the problem must be well-conditioned
2. the algorithm that is used must be stable.

Without getting into too much detail, the condition number of some problem with input and output is the sensitivity of the output when the input changes a little bit.
The logistic map is a chaotic system, and chaotic systems have sensitive dependence on initial conditions. So the problem is not well-conditioned, and therefore whatever algorithm we choose, the predictions will not be accurate.

This does not exactly answer why that unworthy algorithm was supposed to be stable, but on the other hand, no algorithm can give an accurate answer, and this algorithm gives a guess within the range of the problem. So, in a sense, that algorithm is as good as it can get.